# Ways to output video using C?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

I do a lot of physical modeling in C, and for a long time I've been using a roundabout way of animating these models; grid the system to an array of chars and write to a numerically ordered PPM file, then use `convert *.ppm video.gif` and wait.  The output is fine, the time it takes to run?  Not so much.  It can take a handful of minutes to produce a video from a simulation that takes a second to run.

I'm convinced that there must be a more efficient way.  The first thing I tried was SDL; I was able to produce video with it, but I'm doing this on a remote server, and SDL's performance over SSH is beyond abysmal.  Maybe 0.7 FPS.

I've tried using ffmpeg as well, but I haven't had luck with getting it to work; not sure why.  If there's no better solution I'll renew efforts in solving the ffmpeg problem.

Ideally, I'd like a simple way to avoid outputting all those intermediate files in the first place.  Are there any C libraries that would allow me to sequentially combine pixel arrays into frames of an animation?  Preferably *relatively* simple?

Comment: You just need to write a c program that reads data from video files and then outputs the video on the screen.

Comment: you might be able to "stream" it using some encoding [libav*] https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with `ffmpeg`. There is a lot of [documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) and even some [example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-example_8c-source.html). Try ask specific questions about your issues with `ffmpeg` either here on SO either in `ffmpeg` [forums](https://www.ffmpeg.org/contact.html#Forums).